# C# .Net - write data in xml by using existing structure/schema

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an API which creates a sample xml based on a schema file. Here is the link to the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx

Now, suppose the sample xml generated is as follows:

```
<Employee>
   <Name>Bond</Name>
   <Address>abc,unknown street</Address>
   <phone>0000000000</phone>
<Employee>
```

I have a employee DB table consisting of thousands of employee records. What I want is to write those records in the xml format created above (table has many non-required columns also so can't use `dataset.writexml`).

What is the right approach of doing this ? Should I edit the first node as per the first record and then copy the whole node into same xml, write the record then repeat the process till end of records? Or is there a better approach of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You need to show code you've tried and specify a more specific problem.

Comment: if you create a object that matches the data model, such as an employee Class contains all the employee details as properties, and it implements IEnumerable, then you can serialize/Deserialize this class to xml.

Comment: @Jegan Can't do that. Because I don't know what the properties of the class would be. The fields are determined by the xsd file at runtime.

Comment: Then use a Dictionary or Tuple that takes a field and the value during runtime, parse that into serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of serializing and Deserializing Objects to xml.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("DocumentElement")]
public class Documentelement
{
    [XmlElement]
    public PartInfo[] PartInfo { get; set; }
}

public class PartInfo
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNo { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }        
    public DateTime InstallDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime InstallTill { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{

    private PartInfo details_1()
    {
        PartInfo details = new PartInfo
        {
            ID = 0,
            Name = "QVR",
            PartNo = "A11",
            SerialNo = 453,
            Parameter = "C -11",

            // This you should add as date time,  I just used the string to parse your time that you showed in your example.
            InstallDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-04T17:16:56.383+05:30"),
            InstallTill = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-15T17:16:56.3830837+05:30")
        };
        return details;
    }

    private PartInfo details_2()
    {
        PartInfo details = new PartInfo
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "EAFR",
            PartNo = "B07",
            SerialNo = 32,
            Parameter = "B-16",

            // This you should add as date time,  I just used the string to parse your time that you showed in your example.
            InstallDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-18T17:17:44.589+05:30"),
            InstallTill = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-28T17:17:44.589+05:30")
        };
        return details;
    }

    public void setXmlValues()
    {            
        Documentelement testOut = new Documentelement { PartInfo = new[] { details_1(), details_2() }};

        xml_serialise(testOut);

        Documentelement testIn = xml_deserialise();
        int val = testIn.PartInfo[0].ID;
        DateTime dt = testIn.PartInfo[0].InstallDate;
        string shortTime = dt.ToShortTimeString();

    }


    private void xml_serialise(Documentelement test)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Documentelement));


        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, test);
        }
    }

    private Documentelement xml_deserialise()
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Documentelement));

        Documentelement test;

        using (TextReader writer = new StreamReader("test.xml"))
        {
            test = (Documentelement)ser.Deserialize(writer);
        }

        return test;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use `xsd.exe` (one of the VS command-line tools) to generate a schema from the sample XML, and then use `xsd.exe` with the schema to generate a C# class. This class is ready to use with serialization, so you could convert your data into a `List<GeneratedClass>` and then [serialize it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx). Not saying it's the best approach, but I've used it before successfully.

Comment: I had this approach in mind initially. But the xsd is given to the program at runtime. So this approach would involve invoking xsd.exe at runtime, compiling classes on the fly and then using reflection to serialize it into xml. A bit tedious and error prone I guess.